# No bugs, but For , If statement not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

The code below executes but the:

```
For i = 2 To lRow

    If .Range("A" & i).Value = rng1 Then
        If .Range("C" & i).Value = rng2 Then
            lastcell = .Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    End If

Next i
```

Does not seem to be doing what I have intended. What I intended was that if the cell A & i's value = lets say rng1, if that is true then move on to the next parameter and check if that i's C column cell = rng2 if that is correct then take that row i's B column and set cell "C3" on the proof tab equal to B & i's value. Then move on to the next i; if it finds another B that fit the two conditions above, then set cell c3.offset(1) = to that i's value. This unfortunately is not working for me. ANyone have any suggestions :)

This is what it looks like when I run the code:

[image]

[image]

```
 Sub Extract_Bank_Amount()

Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, lastcell As Range
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Bank Statement")

Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B1")
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B3")
Set lastcell = wb.Sheets("Proof").Range("C3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


wb.Sheets("Bank Statement").Activate

With ws

    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow

        If .Range("A" & i).Value = rng1 Then
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = rng2 Then
                lastcell = .Range("B" & i).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `not working for me` does not describe the problem. so there is no way to even guess what your code does that you do not want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the next empty cell each time you add a value to the end of the list.

```
Sub Extract_Bank_Amount()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, lastcell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Bank Statement")

    Set rng1 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B1")
    Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B3")

    wb.Sheets("Bank Statement").Activate

    With ws

        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = rng1 Then
                If .Range("C" & i).Value = rng2 Then

                    With wb.Sheets("Proof")
                        .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
                    End With

                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I would give the ranges on "Payroll Journal" meaningful names then used their Defined Names to refer to them.

```
wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B1").Name = "PayrollB1"
wb.Sheets("Payroll Journal").Range("B3").Name = "PayrollB3"
```

This will allow you to get rid of a lot of the fluff.

```
Sub Extract_Bank_Amount2()

    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Bank Statement")

        For Each cell In .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

            If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Range("PayrollB1").Value Then
                If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("PayrollB3").Value Then

                    With wb.Sheets("Proof")
                        .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.Value
                    End With

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

You should also download [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com).  Rubberduck is a COM add-in for the VBA IDE that will help you debug and optimise your code. Most importantly for me it saves me a ton of time by formatting my code for me.